# How do I consume another component's property value in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs

I have this data in a component:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactsData {

    public CONTACTS: Contact[] = [
        { id: "1", firstname: "Maxxx", lastname: "Smith", email: "max@gmail.com" },
        { id: "2", firstname: "Chris", lastname: "Raches", email: "chris@gmail.com" },
        { id: "3", firstname: "Michael", lastname: "Alloy", email: "michael@gmail.com" },
        { id: "4", firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", email: "john@gmail.com" },
        { id: "5", firstname: "Jenny", lastname: "Doe", email: "jenny@gmail.com" }
    ];
```

I'm trying to access it from another service, but I get "Cannot find name 'CONTACTS'":

```
import {ContactsData} from "./data";
import {Contact} from "./contact";

@Injectable()
export class ContactService{
  getContacts(){
      return Promise.resolve(ContactsData.CONTACTS); // Error here
  }
```

I've obviously skipped a step I don't understand - please point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject ContactsData in ContactService.

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  constructor(private data: ContactsData) {}

  getContacts() {
    return Promise.resolve(this.data.CONTACTS); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get: `ReferenceError: CONTACTS is not defined.`

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/aXlzW9T1qzGdchmnvHwz?p=preview. Post a plunkr reproducing the problem if you want more help.